# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManager

Tags: java

I have the following problem, in my application I would like to have some kind of login. I have following code: (Inspiration here on the web)

```
 public boolean login(String username, String password)
    {
       try{
            EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
            entr.begin();

        TypedQuery<Users> query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.login = :login AND u.password = :pass", Users.class);        
        query.setParameter("login", username);
        query.setParameter("pass", password); 
        try{ 
            Users u = query.getSingleResult();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        }catch(javax.persistence.NoResultException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        }
        finally{
        em.close();
        }

    }
```

When I run it and try to log in, the console will write the following message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManager.
```

Can you help me? I have no idea what it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you close em in the finally, then next time you call this method it would be closed. maybe you should try end the transaction there instead.

Comment: Okay,  but what do I have to write in the finally? I cant do try-catch without finally. Where exactly should that close be?

Comment: you can do try-cach without finally, and in your code you don't need EntityTransaction at all, since you are just doing a read